# 502 Bad GateWay. When send a file as response in flask application deployed on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, nginx, flask, ubuntu-16.04, gunicorn

I have built a flask application and deployed on `Ubuntu 16.04` by using `gunicorn`. This works very fine but doesn't work for only a request.
According to the requirement, the application should be able to let admin download a file, which is DB backup file. 
So the application creates a sql dump file and sends that to the user by using the following code.

```
    from common.backup import Backup
    me = Backup()
    result = me.dump()
    full_path = result['full_path']
    file_name = result['file_name']
    contents = open(full_path).read()
    response = make_response(contents)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s" % (file_name)
    return response
```

It does work on local, but doesn't work. I think the proxy configuration might have been incorrect.
I will post nginx config.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name <IP_ADDRESS>;


access_log /var/log/nginx/<APP_NAME>-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/<APP_NAME>-error.log info;
keepalive_timeout   5;

#sendfile        on;

location / {
    client_max_body_size 5M;
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/<APP_NAME>/<APP_NAME>.sock;
}
}
```

Please have a look at this and let me know your solution.

Best regards,
Alexis

Comment: Can you run gunicorn on http instead of socket and test if it works with gunicorn http? You basically want to isolate if adding Nginx creates the problem or gunicron itself creates the problem

Comment: It does work on gunicorn.

Comment: Can you provide debug info when your invoke the file download while using nginx? Use this article to get the debug info http://tarunlalwani.com/post/how-to-debug-nginx-reverse-proxy-issues-php-fpm-gunicorn-uwsgi/

Comment: `3 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xx.xxx.xx, server: xx.xxx.x.xxx, request: "POST /settings/db HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/pp/pp.sock:/settings/db"`

Comment: The mount path for windows is different it would be something like `/media/sf_project`. See this article https://www.howtogeek.com/187703/how-to-access-folders-on-your-host-machine-from-an-ubuntu-virtual-machine-in-virtualbox/

Comment: No, the article is not a value of my issue. Please listen to me. It does work fine with wsgi as well. My concern is subprocess call within code. Perhaps does nginx/wsgi block `subprocess.call(command, shell = True)` like things?